# Text mining frequency with ggplot

Tags: r, tidytext

I am working with a dataset called [HappyDB](https://rit-public.github.io/HappyDB/) for a class presentation and analyzing demographic differences in word frequency. I'm using tidytext for most of the analyses, and using [their online guide](https://www.tidytextmining.com/tidytext.html) to create most of my visuals. However, I'm running into a problem with the code to create the frequency plot of words with labels. My dataset is structured differently from theirs, and I thought I was accounting for it but I evidently was not. This is their sample code to generate the graph (comparing Jane Austen with the Bronte sisters and H.G. Wells)

```
library(tidyr)

frequency <- bind_rows(mutate(tidy_bronte, author = "Brontë Sisters"),
                   mutate(tidy_hgwells, author = "H.G. Wells"), 
                   mutate(tidy_books, author = "Jane Austen")) %>% 
mutate(word = str_extract(word, "[a-z']+")) %>%
count(author, word) %>%
group_by(author) %>%
mutate(proportion = n / sum(n)) %>% 
select(-n) %>% 
spread(author, proportion) %>% 
gather(author, proportion, `Brontë Sisters`:`H.G. Wells`)

library(scales)

# expect a warning about rows with missing values being removed
ggplot(frequency, aes(x = proportion, y = `Jane Austen`, color = abs(`Jane Austen` - proportion))) +
  geom_abline(color = "gray40", lty = 2) +
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.1, size = 2.5, width = 0.3, height = 0.3) +
  geom_text(aes(label = word), check_overlap = TRUE, vjust = 1.5) +
  scale_x_log10(labels = percent_format()) +
  scale_y_log10(labels = percent_format()) +
  scale_color_gradient(limits = c(0, 0.001), low = "darkslategray4", high = "gray75") +
  facet_wrap(~author, ncol = 2) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  labs(y = "Jane Austen", x = NULL)
```

And that code generates this plot:

[image]

I'm hoping to emulate this with demographics in my dataset, but keep getting errors. Here is my code, which uses a dataset that I have already tidied:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidytext)
library(stringr) 

windowsFonts(Franklin=windowsFont("Franklin Gothic Demi"))

marriedmen <- tidy_hm[which(tidy_hm$marital =="married" &
                               tidy_hm$gender == "m"),]
marriedwomen <- tidy_hm[which(tidy_hm$marital =="married" &
                                tidy_hm$gender == "f"),]
singlemen <- tidy_hm[which(tidy_hm$marital =="single" &
                             tidy_hm$gender == "m"),]

frequency <- bind_rows(mutate(marriedmen, status = "Married men"),
                       mutate(marriedwomen, status = "Married women"), 
                       mutate(singlemen, status = "Single men")) %>% 
  count(status, word) %>%
  group_by(status) %>%
  mutate(proportion = n / sum(n)) %>% 
  select(-n) %>% 
  spread(status, proportion) %>% 
  gather(status, proportion, `Married women`:`Single men`)

library(scales)

# expect a warning about rows with missing values being removed
ggplot(frequency, aes(x = proportion, y = 'Married men', color = abs(`Married men` - proportion)) +
  geom_abline(color = "gray40", lty = 2) +
  geom_jitter(alpha = 0.1, size = 2.5, width = 0.3, height = 0.3) +
  geom_text(aes(label = word), check_overlap = TRUE, vjust = 1.5) +
  scale_x_log10(labels = percent_format()) +
  scale_y_log10(labels = percent_format()) +
  scale_color_gradient(limits = c(0, 0.001), low = "darkslategray4", high = "gray75") +
  facet_wrap(~status, ncol = 2) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  labs(y = NULL, x = NULL)
```

But I keep getting this error:

`Error in log(x, base) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function`

I tried removing the scale rows, but that caused a bunch of data to get eliminated and the plot didn't look anything like it was supposed to, and had no line, labels, or colors. I'm pretty new to r and coding in general so any help is appreciated.

Comment: In your `ggplot` call you have `y = 'Married men'`, which is setting y to be that character string.  It looks like you meant to use back-ticks rather than apostrophes, as you do with the `color` element (assuming `Married men` is a variable name in the `frequency` dataframe)

Comment: @AndrewGustar Yes thank you for that catch. But changing that now gives me this error: `(Error in combine_vars(data, params$plot_env, vars, drop = params$drop): At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting)`

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing a bit of detail of the structure of your dataframe, but I wonder if the `spread` then `gather` is having the effect of removing the `status` variable, which you are trying to use for faceting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I cannot quite figure out what has gone wrong here without seeing something of the structure of your dataframe. You could check out this question about making a reproducible example in R for help on how to make a small example dataset so that we can help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example